# Delete a relationship using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have created my own database model using Entity Framework Code First with the latest Entity Framework version.

I have this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string InterestIn { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<User> FromWhomIsFriend { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> WantsToDo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesReceived { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output = string.Empty;

        output = String.Format("UserId: {0}, Name: {1}, Age: {2}, City: {3}, " +
            "Country: {4}, Email: {5}, InterestIn: {6}",
            UserId, Name, Age, City, Country, Email, InterestIn);

        return output;
    }
}
```

And its configuration class:

```
class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        Property(d => d.Name).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.Age).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.City).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.Country).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.Email).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.InterestIn).IsRequired();

        HasMany(d => d.MessagesSent).WithRequired(l => l.SentByUser).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasMany(d => d.MessagesReceived).WithRequired(l => l.SentToUser).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasMany(d => d.Friends).
            WithMany(d => d.FromWhomIsFriend).
            Map(c =>
                {
                    c.ToTable("UserFriends");
                    c.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                    c.MapRightKey("FriendId");
                });
        HasMany(d => d.WantsToDo).
            WithMany(a => a.Users).
            Map(t =>
                {
                    t.ToTable("UserActivities");
                    t.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                    t.MapRightKey("ActivityId");
                });
    }
}
```

To represent this many-to-many self relationship:

[image]

Now I have a problem: I don't know how to delete friend relationship. With SQL I will do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM UserFriend
WHERE (userId = user1_id   AND friendId = friend1_id) OR
      (userId = friend1_id AND friendId = user1_id)
```

`user1_id`: is the user who wants to delete a friend relationship.
`friend1_id`: is the friend user1 wants to remove as friend.

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove friend from the collection:

```
user.Friends.Remove(friendToRemove);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And, what about `FromWhomIsFriend `? Do I have to do the same with this collection?

Comment: If you're using proxies (your collections are virtual), than association fixup will be performed by proxy (`user` will be deleted from `friendToRemove.FromWhomIsFriend`).

Answer (score 0):

So, if I undestand correctly, if the user User1 is friends with User2, the relationship will either be in `user1.Friends` or in `user1.FromWhomIsFriend`.

You should check where the relationship is, and remove it accordingly.

```
 public void RemoveFriend(User user, User friend)
 {
   if (user1.Friends.Contains(friend));
      user1.Friends.Remove(friend);
   if (user1.FromWhomIsFriend.Contains(friend));
      user1.FromWhomIsFriend.Remove(friend);
 }
```